# DigitalOcean guide to installing Rails on Ubuntu with rbenv doesn't work for me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, digital-ocean, rbenv

I'm trying to install Rails with this guide:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-14-04
I don't really understand all the commands:

```
cd
git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git .rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc

git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

So I just copied each line and pasted it to the terminal and hit enter
Then I did:

```
rbenv install -v 2.2.3
```

and when I tried to verify the version with:

```
ruby -v
```

I got an error, something like: **... command exists in these Ruby versions:**

I just copied the commands and pasted them, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Installing a Ruby doesn't immediately make it your current Ruby. Before trying to run your newly installed Ruby, make it your current Ruby with rbenv global 2.2.3 or rbenv local 2.2.3 or rbenv shell 2.2.3. (See rbenv --help for what those mean.) Once you've set the Ruby you're using you can run commands that it provides, like ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I chose to use rvm. If you don't mind switching, you can follow this. It'll get you up and running super quick.

The most basic Vagrant box you can find to get Rails on Ubuntu. (This uses Ubuntu 14, but you can just change the box, should work roughly the same).

https://github.com/joelgerard/rails-vagrant

Also, checkout the [bootstrap.sh](https://github.com/joelgerard/rails-vagrant/blob/master/bootstrap.sh) if you want straight forward BASH.